# How to add an integer unique id to query results - __efficiently__?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Given a query, `select * from ...` (that might be part of CTAS statement)

The goal is to add an additional column, `ID`, where `ID` is a unique integer.

```
select ... as ID,* from ...
```

P.s.

- `ID` does not have to be sequential (there could be gaps)
- The ID could be arbitrary (doesn't have to represent a specific order within the result set)

---

**row_number** logically solves the problem -

```
select row_number() over () as ID,* from ...
```

The problem is, that at least for now, global **row_number** (no **partition by**) is being implemented using a single reducer (hive) / task (spark).

Comment: Starting with Hive 2.2 you can generate an UUID instead of an sequence - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12721

Comment: And since the Hive UUID function simply calls `java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()` you should be able to do something similar with `reflect` in any Hive version > https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFUUID.java

Comment: Been there, done that :-). UUID is 36 bytes Vs. 4 of INT or 8 of BIGINT. You pay for it in storage and in any operation you do - WHERE, GROUP BY, JOIN, ORDER BY etc.

Comment: 36 bytes as STRING, but only 16 bytes as BINARY *(although the conversion to Hive BINARY would require an UDF)*. And you've got what you pay for i.e. for a very large dataset, the "unicity" of a 32-bit random value is questionable. Same dilemma as poor-man CRC32 vs. cumbersome cryptographic MD5 or SHA1...

Answer (score 1):

**hive**

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks=1000;
set hivevar:buckets=10000;
```

`hivevar:buckets` should be high enough relatively to the number of reducers (`mapred.reduce.tasks`), so the rows will be evenly distributed between the reduces.

---

```
select  1 + x + (row_number() over (partition by x) - 1) * ${hivevar:buckets}  as id
       ,t.*

from   (select  t.*
               ,abs(hash(rand())) % ${hivevar:buckets} as x      

        from    t
        ) t
```

**spark-sql**

```
select  1 + x + (row_number() over (partition by x) - 1) * 10000  as id
       ,t.*

from   (select  t.*
               ,abs(hash(rand())) % 10000 as x      

        from    t
        ) t
```

---

**For both hive and spark-sql**

The `rand()` is used to generate a good distribution.
If You already have in your query a column / combination of columns with good distribution (might be unique, not a must) you might use it instead, e.g. -

```
select    1 + (abs(hash(col1,col)) % 10000) 
        + (row_number() over (partition by abs(hash(col1,col)) % 10000) - 1) * 10000  as id
       ,t.*

from    t
```

Comment: Side note: why hash a random value? Since hashing is deterministic, that will not change the probability of collision...

Comment: If you have column(s) with a known good distribution you can use it instead, but beware of using values that might be skewed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spark-sql your best bet would be to use the inbuilt function

monotonically_increasing_id

which generates unique random id in a separate column.
And as you said you don't need it to be sequential so this should ideally suffice your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution from Manoj Kumar: https://github.com/manojkumarvohra/hive-hilo

- A stateful UDF is created which maintains a HI/LO counters to
  increment the sequences.
- The HI value is maintained as distribute atomic long in zookeeper.
- The HI value is incremented & fetched for every n LO (default 200)
  iterations.
- The UDF supports a single String argument which is the sequence name
  used to maintain zNodes in zookeeper.

Usage:

```
FunctionName( sequenceName, lowvalue[optional], seedvalue[optional])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for a globally unique id service https://github.com/spinaki/distributed-unique-id
It has a docker image too which you can test quickly.