# Creating Star Schema (Dimensions and Fact Table) in Hadoop Hive from a single csv file

Tags: hadoop, hive, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

Im completely new to Datawarehouse, OLAP and hive. I do have a single csv file containing training data about a online market like ebay (see Column Data). My task is to create a star schema in hive (via Data Analytics Studio, Spark, or whatever).

I scaffolded the dimension as followed:

[image: Fact and Dimensions]

How can i create those dimensions tables and especially generate a new ID for each line?
My `SELECT New_Guid(), listing_title, listing_subtitle, listing_type_code, start_price, buy_it_now_price, buy_it_now_listed_flag, qty_available_per_listing From auctions`, which i found on another tutorial. But `New_Guid()` does not work at all in my Data Analytics Studio.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How to get UUID or numerical surrogate key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58625717/2700344

Comment: debatable whether price is a dimensional attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no history in the dimensions, and leaving aside if good dimension design or not:

1. For each required Dimension:

   - read the csv and extract relevant fields with distinct applied to temp_table
   - add a sequence number to each row using `select (row_number() over()), Col1, Col2, col3, col4 from temp_table` & persist to dimension_table
2. For the fact table:

   - read the csv and extract relevant fields with applied to temp_table
   - add a sequence number to each row using `select (row_number() over()), Col1, Col2, col3, col4 from temp_table` and store in another temp_table_2
   - JOIN with appropriate statement from temp_table_2 to dimensuions looking up / selecting the sequence number giving temp_table_3
   - insert the keys only from temp_table_3 to fact_table